# Staff directory with CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a staff directory the name, email and number. On desktop I'd like the information to go straight across but once it goes mobile the email and number will under the name.

I'm stumped with the html. Any advice?

```
<div class="grid-container">
     <h3 class="name">James Francis <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:james@balancinglifesissues.com">james@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    <div class="number-grid">
      <a class="number-grid-a" href="tel:3478661021">Mobile: 347-866-1021</a>
      <a class="number-grid-b" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x6</a>
    </div>

    <h3 class="name">Trish Morrison <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:trish@balancinglifesissues.com">trish@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    <div class="number-grid">
      <a class="number-grid-c" href="tel:9144943571">Mobile: 914-494-3571</a>
      <a class=:number-grid-d href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x2</a>
    </div>

    <h3 class="name">Kim Barna <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:kim@balancinglifesissues.com">kim@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    <a class="number" href="tel:2039843040">Mobile: 203-984-3040</a>

     <h3 class="name">Sean Mullin <span>- Assistance Account Manager</span></h3>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:billing@balancinglifesissues.com">billing@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    <div class="number-grid">
      <a class="number-grid-e" href="tel:9146409366">Mobile: 914-640-9366</a>
      <a class="number-grid-f" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x7</a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="name">Samela Grant <span>- Accounts Payable Manager</span></h3>
    <a class="email" href="mailto:samela@balancinglifesissues.com">samela@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    <div class="number-grid">
      <a class="number-grid-g" href="tel:3478661021">Mobile: 347-866-1021</a>
      <a class="number-grid-h" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x5</a>
   </div>

   <h3 class="name">Laverne McGarrell <span>- Clerk</span></h3>
   <a class="email" href="mailto:laverne@balancinglifesissues.com">laverne@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
   <a class="number" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x3</a>


   <h3 class="name">Lindsay Gilmore <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
   <a class="email" href="mailto:lindsay@balancinglifesissues.com">lindsay@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
   <div class="number-grid">
     <a class="number-grid-i" href="tel:9146425157">Mobile: 914-642-5157</a>
     <a class="number-grid-j" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x*</a>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Look into media queries or frameworks like Bootstrap

Comment: Mediaqueries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Are you able to adjust the markup? Or are you looking for something to specifically fit this code?

Comment: @NoahWhitmore Yes, I can adjust the markup. Should each contact have their own div?

Comment: Where is your CSS? You have to at least **attempt** this....and yes, each contact should be in a separate div.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was unsure if I had setup my HTML properly. Once I put each contact into their own div I will be able to style as needed. Looking at my question it definitely wasn't specific enough. Appreciate the response.

Comment: @NoahWhitmore Thanks so much for your help. Appreciate the extra resources to read as well.

Comment: @wmc-914 Glad to help! I know that you're new to SO by the way, so welcome! When you feel like your question has been answered, you can mark an answer as accepted by following the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - of course, don't feel compelled to accept my answer because it was first. I just thought I would remind you since this is your first question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no worries about support IE9 or lower, you could use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

However, creating a simple grid is pretty easy...

- Separate each set of details (in your case, each contact) into its own `<div>`. I applied `.grid-group` to each of these groups.
- Separate each individual detail (name, email, number) into its own `<div>`. I applied `.grid-cell` to each of these
- Apply `float:left` and `width:100%` to each `.grid-cell` - this will cause each contact to be 100% width by default
- Set a `@media` rule to change each `.grid-group` to `width:33.3%` when the viewport is `768px` or below. Now, when the viewport is smaller, the cells will 'grid' to be one third width

I have included the snippet and code below. But it's kind of hard to check `@media` queries in the Stack Snippet tool. So, here is a demo on CodePen: https://codepen.io/noahjwhitmore/pen/eyLwrd/

I would, obviously, leave the rest of the styling up to you. But, hopefully this is a good starting point.

### More Resources

You should definitely check out more information about `media` queries on some reputable sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). When I first started learning about `media` queries, [this article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) was pretty invaluable.

The example that I have created here does not use Flexbox, so it is a little more complicated than some other grids that you may see. Once you have `media` rules and Flexbox working together, it can be a beautiful thing. Modern browsers support the use of Flexbox and I highly suggest that you [look into it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Keep in mind, it is not supported in IE9 and lower, and there are still some ongoing IE issues, but it is becoming more and more standard.

Keep in mind that there are also alot of frameworks that already have built-in grids for responsive design.

- Obviously [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) - v3.3.7 has a grid that does not use Flexbox. The newer version of Bootstrap (v4) changed and now their built-in grid ***is*** Flexbox based
- Milligram is a very minimal framework, and has a really nice Flexbox based grid built-in

```css
/* Stuff specific to your markup */
/* Make things start at the same size */
h3, a {
  font-size:initial;
  font-weight:initial;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/* Make phone numbers appear on their own line */
a[href^="tel:"] {
  display:block;
}


/************************
 * Extremely Basic Grid *
 ***********************/
.grid-group, .grid-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-cell {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Clearfix */
.grid-group {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.grid-group:before, .grid-group:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.grid-group:after {
  clear: both;
}


/*
   Cells will be 33.3% until screen
   is smaller than 768px when cells
   become 100% (which was set above
   in the .grid-cell declaration)
*/
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .one-third {
    width:33.3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">James Francis <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:james@balancinglifesissues.com">james@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a href="tel:3478661021">Mobile: 347-866-1021</a>
      <a href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x6</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Trish Morrison <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:trish@balancinglifesissues.com">trish@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a href="tel:9144943571">Mobile: 914-494-3571</a>
      <a href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Kim Barna <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:kim@balancinglifesissues.com">kim@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="number" href="tel:2039843040">Mobile: 203-984-3040</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Sean Mullin <span>- Assistance Account Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:billing@balancinglifesissues.com">billing@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a href="tel:9146409366">Mobile: 914-640-9366</a>
      <a href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x7</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Samela Grant <span>- Accounts Payable Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:samela@balancinglifesissues.com">samela@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a href="tel:3478661021">Mobile: 347-866-1021</a>
      <a href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Laverne McGarrell <span>- Clerk</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:laverne@balancinglifesissues.com">laverne@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="number" href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-group">
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <h3 class="name">Lindsay Gilmore <span>- Account Manager</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a class="email" href="mailto:lindsay@balancinglifesissues.com">lindsay@balancinglifesissues.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-cell one-third">
      <a href="tel:9146425157">Mobile: 914-642-5157</a>
      <a href="tel:9147629075">Main: 914-762-9075 x*</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```